# Constraint for member named "identity" in grails 2.5.2 generates exception when mocking for test

Tags: grails, grails-domain-class

In my Grails 2.5.2 application, I have a domain class with a member named "identity". The member has a constraint looking like this:

```
static constraints = {
    identity maxSize: 15, nullable: false, unique: true
}
```

My unit test mocks the domain class like this:

```
@TestFor(CustomerController)
@Mock(Customer)
class CustomerControllerSpec extends Specification {
...
```

...but when running the test I get this exception:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.Family.identity() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[maxSize:15, nullable:false, unique:true]]
Possible solutions: identity(groovy.lang.Closure)

    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.groovy.MappingConfigurationBuilder.invokeMethod(MappingConfigurationBuilder.groovy:55)
    at com.twentyonegrams.mailportal.shipment.Customer._clinit__closure1(Customer.groovy:10)
    at com.twentyonegrams.mailportal.shipment.Customer._clinit__closure1(Customer.groovy)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.groovy.MappingConfigurationBuilder.evaluate(MappingConfigurationBuilder.groovy:83)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.config.AbstractGormMappingFactory.createMappedForm(AbstractGormMappingFactory.java:63)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.GormKeyValueMappingFactory.createMappedForm(GormKeyValueMappingFactory.java:39)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.GormKeyValueMappingFactory.createMappedForm(GormKeyValueMappingFactory.java:28)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.KeyValuePersistentEntity.<init>(KeyValuePersistentEntity.java:35)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.keyvalue.mapping.config.KeyValueMappingContext.createPersistentEntity(KeyValueMappingContext.java:95)
    at org.grails.datastore.mapping.model.AbstractMappingContext.addPersistentEntities(AbstractMappingContext.java:174)
    at grails.test.mixin.domain.DomainClassUnitTestMixin.mockDomains(DomainClassUnitTestMixin.groovy:86)
    at org.spockframework.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtil.java:153)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.model.MethodInfo.invoke(MethodInfo.java:84)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$1$2.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:49)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.TestRuleInterceptor.intercept(TestRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:88)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.AbstractRuleInterceptor$1.evaluate(AbstractRuleInterceptor.java:37)
    at grails.test.runtime.TestRuntimeJunitAdapter$3$4.evaluate(TestRuntimeJunitAdapter.groovy:76)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.builtin.ClassRuleInterceptor.intercept(ClassRuleInterceptor.java:38)
    at org.spockframework.runtime.extension.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
    at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
```

Are there there any alternative ways to enter a constraint or to mock a domain that makes it possible to avoid this exception?

The problem persist in Grails 2.5.3.

I filed a [bug report](https://github.com/grails/grails-core/issues/9505) about this as well.

Answer (score 0):

for test a constraint like unique, which ensures that the database table contains no duplicate values use mockForConstraintsTests(Customer), [identity]) ;

Comment: Isn't @Mock(Customer) doing exactly that? I cannot figure out where to put the call to mockForConstraintsTests because I get the exception before anything is called in the Spok Spec. Even before setupSpec.

Comment: Hi, I check this scenario and found identity is reserved keyword , we can find the  reserved keywords from [here : ](https://grails.org/wiki/Reserved%20Names) . You can't use reserved keyword .If you use another name which is not in reserved in database instead of identity, it will work fine.